# Unable to find override for dict.iteritems(class)

Tags: python

I've got a class that has replaced `__iter__` to hide extra unneeded data. I've made the rest of my code backwards compatible by setting `iteritems` to either `dict.iteritems` or `dict.items` depending on the python version, and I can then call `iteritems(class_object)`, but it doesn't seem to work well with my class.

It'll be easier to explain with an example:

```
class Test(dict):
    def __init__(self, some_dict):
        self.some_dict = some_dict
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(self.some_dict)
    def __iter__(self):
        for k, v in self.some_dict.iteritems():
            yield k, v['value']

test_dict = {
    'a': {'value': 'what',
          'hidden': 123},
    'b': {'value': 'test'}
}
```

If I do `Test(test_dict).__iter__()`, then it correctly returns `{'a': 'what', 'b': 'test'}`

If I add `iteritems = __iter__` to the class, then it also works when doing `Test(test_dict).iteritems()`

However, no matter what I try, doing `dict.iteritems(Test(test_dict))` defaults to the standard dict iterating, and returns `{'a': {'hidden': 123, 'value': 'what'}, 'b': {'value': 'test'}}`

I've tried a couple of trace functions but they don't go deep enough to figure out what's going on.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are inheriting from `dict` but keeping an extra reference to to the dictionary in `self.some_dict`. You could just use `self.iteritems()`. Note that normally, iteration over a dictionary only yields *keys*, not key-value pairs.

Comment: Why do you need `dict.iteritems` to work? That's not a regular Python method, it reaches into the `dict` internals. Since you subclassed `dict` that's possible and permissible.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Have I been doing it wrong with `__init__`? I'd like to inherit all the normal dict functions but still be able to easily access and change all the data. As to not doing `self.iteritems()`, it's mainly for keeping it consistent with the rest of the code. I've been using `iteritems(dict)` to keep it compatible with both python 2 and 3, and I'd prefer to keep this within the same style if possible.

Comment: `dict.iteritems` is the method of the superclass. It ignores any overrides in subclasses.

Comment: @fafl: much more importantly, its implementation doesn't use any other methods on the instance. It just reaches straight into the struct that makes up the instance state and accesses `ma_table` and other C-level data structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dict.iteritems()` method reaches straight into the internal data structures of the `dict` implementation. You passed in a subclass of `dict` so those same data structures are there for it to access. You can't override this behaviour.

Not that `dict.iteritems()` would ever use `__iter__`; the latter produces *keys only*, not key-value pairs!

You should instead define `iteritems` differently; given a `PY3` boolean variable that is `False` for Python 2, `True` otherwise:

```
from operator import methodcaller

iteritems = methodcaller('items' if PY3 else 'iteritems')
```

Now `iteritems(object)` is translated to `object.iteritems()` or `object.items()`, as needed, and the correct method is always called.

Next, to extend dictionary behaviour, instead of subclassing `dict`, I'd subclass [`collections.MutableMapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) <sup>(*)</sup>:

```
from collections import MutableMapping

class Test(MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, some_dict):
        self.some_dict = some_dict.copy()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.some_dict[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.some_dict[key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.some_dict[key]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.some_dict)

    def __iter__(self):
        for k, v in self.some_dict.iteritems():
            yield k, v['value']
```

This implements all the same methods that `dict` provides, *except* for `copy` and the `dict.fromkeys()` class method.

You could instead inherit from [`collections.UserDict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserDict), which adds those two remaining methods:

```
try:
    # Python 2
    from UserDict import UserDict
except ImportError:
    from collections import UserDict


class Test(UserDict):
    def __iter__(self):
        for k, v in self.data.iteritems():
            yield k, v['value']
```

Only an alternate `__iter__` implementation is needed in that case.

In either case, you *still can't use `dict.iteritems` on these objects*, because that method can only work with actual `dict` objects.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> `collections.MutableMapping` is the Python 2 location of that class, the official Python 3 location is `collections.abc.MutableMapping` but there are aliases in place to support Python 2-compatible code.

Comment: Oh damn, that `methodcaller` works great, I've just basically been doing `iteritems = dict.items if PY3 else dict.iteritems`. My classes have already grown [slightly complicated](https://github.com/Peter92/MouseTracks/blob/master/core/ini.py), but at the base of the inheritance it's sort of like `UserDict`, and `MutableMapping` could potentially be used a bit higher up, so it may not be too bad to adapt. Thanks :)

Comment: @Peter: you could also just use [`six.py`](https://github.com/benjaminp/six); it is MIT licensed specifically so you can freely copy it into your project as needed, or you can make it a `setup.py` dependency.

Comment: @Peter: `six` implements `iteritems()` as `iter(d.items())` on Python 3, as that is technically more correct.

Comment: Oh wait a sec, I may have used the code wrong, does the `methodcaller` still completely bypass the class? The `iteritems` in `six.py` is a lot simpler than what I'd have thought though, the file would have been very useful earlier, but some of the other code is completely relying on my own compatibility file :P

Comment: `methodcaller(name_of_method)(object)` will execute the `name_of_method` method on `object`. It doesn't matter what type of object it is. You'll need provide an implementation of `iteritems()` *on your class* if you want it called. If you subclassed `dict` but did not provide your own `iteritems()` implementation, you still would get the wrong results.

Comment: Note: both `MutableMapping` and `UserDict` provide a `iteritems()` method in Python 2. The `MutableMapping` version is basically a loop over `self`, expecting keys: `for key in self: yield (key, self[key])`. The `UserDict` version uses `def iteritems(self): return self.data.iteritems()`

Comment: Ah right, I had actually wondered about how to do that before so cheers. To get the bypass working though, I've just figured I can make a custom `iteritems` to try call `._iteritems_override()` first, then fallback to `.items()` or `.iteritems() if that fails. It's a little too hardcoded for my liking but it would do the job. As to the comment you wrote just then, it's more the override of it I'm after, it's my attempt at making an easy to use config class with a lot of hidden metadata.

Comment: @Peter: I'm not certain why you can't just implement `iteritems()` on the `Config` class?

Comment: It's mainly just for keeping it in line with the rest of the code, I use the `iteritems(dict)` way hundreds of times on the normal dicts, and was trying to get the config class to match a dict as close as possible while having the extra features